# Can singular measures be viewed as vanishing distributions? (Answer No!)

Tags: measure-theory, pr.probability, probability-distributions, fa.functional-analysis

Hello,

Here is my original question: let $\mu$ be a singular measure with respect to the Lebesgue's measure on $R$. Is it true that $\int \psi \mu(d x)=0$ for any test function $\psi\in C_c^\infty(R)$ (smooth functions with compact support)?

Following the suggestion by André Henriques, I will put the answer in the answer box. :-)

Thanks again for everyone! :-)

Anand

p.s. this is related to [my previous post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/70146/distributions-and-measures).

Comment: A non-zero continuous function can be viewed as a distribution. That distribution will then also be non-zero...
What do you mean by "singular"?

Comment: Yes, it is better to put in this way: let $\mu$ be a distribution, singular with respect to Lebesgue's measure. For any test function $\psi\in\mathcal{D}(R)$, do we have $\int_R \psi\mu(d x)=0$?

Comment: After reading your other post, I think that I now understand what you mean by "singular". You're probably thinking of an increasing functions on $\mathbb R$, and you want the derivative of that function to be a measure that is singular w.r.t Lebesgue measure.

Comment: Yes, it is. :-)

Comment: You should also explain what $\mathcal D(R)$ is... it's not clear from the context.

Comment: I am sorry for the lack of explanation. $\mathcal{D}(R)$ is the space of test functions $C_c^\infty(R)$ (smooth functions with compact support) with the usual topology. 

Comment: In view of your answer to André Henriques's comment, I suppose the $f$ and $dx$ in the integrand in your question actually refer to the singular measure that acts as the "derivative" of some increasing, continuous function $g$.  In that case, the answer to your question is no, the integral need not vanish.  Suppose, for example, that $g$ is constant outside some interval $[a,b]$ (so the measure $f\,dx$ concentrates on $[a,b]$) while $\psi$ is identically 1 on $[a,b]$.  Then the integral will be $g(b)-g(a)$.  (Apologies if I misunderstood the question.)

Comment: Anand, you should edit your question and replace it by the comment you gave (second in the thread right now). As it stands, what you wrote about the function $f$ is not true. The Cantor function is a singular continuous function, and clearly if $\psi = 1$ on $[1/3,2/3]$ and is non-negative elsewhere, $\int f\psi dx > 1/6$. 

Comment: @Andreas Blass and Willie Wong, thank you very much. I am clear now.:-)

Comment: Anand: please add all the information that you provided in the comments to the question itself. It is much easier for everyone of it is complete.

Comment: Do you have a question in your revised post?

Comment: The simplest example of a singular measure is the so-called "delta function".  The derivative of the unit step function.  But of course $\int_R \psi(x)\delta(dx) = \psi(0)$.

Comment: @Gerald Edgar, thank you for the simple example. :-)
@S. Carnahan, I think I have understood my question. Thanks! @Mariano, I will revise my post, thanks. :-)

Comment: @Anand: I think that the correct protocol is to type the answer to your question in the answer box, and then click on the check mark to accept your own answer. (Moderators correct me if I'm wrong)

Comment: @André Henriques, thank you for your suggestion. I will do it.:-)


Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading comments by Andreas and Wong, I understand that the above statement is wrong. Professor Gerald Edgar gives the simplest example (at least for me :-) ): delta function is a singular measure, but for any test function $\psi$ not vanishing at zero $\psi(0)\ne 0$, we have that $\int \psi \delta(d x)=\psi(0)\ne 0$.

Thanks everyone for your patience and helps! :-)